# Azure - Remove server" and "x-powered-by" .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, azure, header

I'm deploying a webapi (.net core 3.1) in Azure.
I read this articles...
[How to remove x-powered-by header in .net core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882715/how-to-remove-x-powered-by-header-in-net-core-2-0)
and
[Remove HTTP header on ASP.Net Core 2.2 InProcess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253660/remove-http-header-on-asp-net-core-2-2-inprocess)

I created the web.confi, and de output when i publish, the file are created here "...\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\PubTmp\Out" wiht this structed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true" />
    </security>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\xdws.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

However, still present the "server" and "x-powered-by" information, like this image.

[image info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyVp9.png)

Comment: I published two more times and is now hiding that information.
Thanks anyway

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29488245)?